# Python: Matching nested dict/lists with a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, nested

I have a list of titles as strings. I want to identify any of these titles within which any one of a list of a specific few keywords is found (e.g. 'new excellent iphone 4 8gb' would match with ['4', '8gb']). All of the keywords within these keywords sets must be in the title string to count as a match (i.e. 'iphone 4' would not match with ['4', '8gb']) - and they should be separate words, i.e. i don't want ['4', '8gb'] to match with 'iphone 4s 8gb'. I have these keyword sets in dicts nested inside a list.

My code is below although it is missing a key part, the loop through each of the lists of keywords, which I'm having trouble wrapping my head around. What is the most efficient way, performance wise of writing this to function?

```
cleantitles = ['title1','title2','title3']
models = [{'model': ['4', '8gb'], 'mapped': u'iphone 4 8gb'}, {'model': ['4', '16gb'], 'mapped': u'iphone 4 16gb'}]

for title in cleantitles:
    if all(x in title for x in ???):
        print 'matched something!'
    else:
        print 'no match:('
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to fit this sort of statement in one line is likely to make it unreadable. You need 3 layers of iteration: title, model, keywords. You're currently trying to combine model and keywords into one statement. I would recommend you avoid this.

You're also missing the unpacking of the dictionary using `[key]`,

You'll want something like this:

```
for title in cleantitles:
    for model in models:
        if all(x in title for x in model['model']):
            print('matched something!')
        else:
            print('no match:(')
```

Never prematurely optimise your code. Write the code in the simplest way you can, then if this isn't fast enough for your situation, refactor.

Comment: Thankyou, I actually had just re-written it to exactly this. However it is matching any occurences of the keywords - I need it to only match if there is a space before/after the keyword in the title. E.g. - '4' is being found in iphone 4s as well as iphone 4. How can I do this?

Comment: If that's your situation, you probably want to look at using regular expressions rather than simple string comparison.